# Return more than one result

Tags: c#

I have a bug that I need more than one result from a `foreach` without creating a new collection in the method. I need to get rid of the `foreach` however I don`t know what LINQ method to use.

I have tried,

```
return basket.Items.SelectMany(
    item => item.Id == orderComplimentaryUtilities.Where(o => o.Id));

public static IEnumerable<OrderItem> WhichUtilitiesAreAlreadyInBasket(
    this 
    IEnumerable<OrderComplimentaryUtility.OrderComplimentaryUtility> 
            orderComplimentaryUtilities,
    Order basket)
{
    if (basket == null || orderComplimentaryUtilities == null)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<OrderItem>();
    }
    
    foreach (var orderComplimentaryUtility in orderComplimentaryUtilities)
    {
        return basket.Items.Where(item => item.Id == orderComplimentaryUtility.Id);
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<OrderItem>();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You can use IntersectBy on the id

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are looking to join the data from two sequences (`orderComplimentaryUtilities` and `basket`), and return the data from `basket` where they match by `id`.

You can accomplish this with a LINQ `join`:

```
public static IEnumerable<OrderItem> WhichUtilitiesAreAlreadyInBasket(
    this IEnumerable<OrderComplimentaryUtility.OrderComplimentaryUtility> orderComplimentaryUtilities, 
    Order basket)
{
    if (basket == null || orderComplimentaryUtilities == null)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<OrderItem>();
    }
    
    var items = orderComplimentaryUtilities
                .Join(basket,
                      u => u.ID,
                      b => b.ID,
                      (u, b) => b);

    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains` if you separate out the ids into a collection:

```
var ids = orderComplimentaryUtility.Select(i => i.id).ToArray();
return basket.Items.Where(item => ids.Contains(item.Id));
```

If this is all in-memory, you could inline the `Select` into the `Where` clause, but that may not work if you're querying a SQL data source that cannot convert the `Select` into an `IN` clause.

Comment: to clarify, it is my understanding that allocations occur "in memory".

Comment: Since `basket` is an `Order` object you're probably right - so you can try to inline it and see if that works, otherwise creating one intermediate array (with a short lifespan) should not be a problem.